# What's going wrong with the use of my 'measure of goodness of fit' formulas?

Tags: statistics, chi-squared

This question regards goodness of fit (Chi-squared distribution)

[image]

Comment: I forget the actual formulas, but if the point is to have the first and second formulas being *equivalent*, then it is clear from just algebra that your formulae are not equivalent. An expanded form of the first formula which is equivalent to it would be $\sum_i \frac{O_i^2}{E_i}-2O_i+E_i$.

Comment: I know for sure the formulas are correct. With your expanded form, we know that Oi and Ei are the same, so we can simplify -2Oi+Ei = -2Oi+Oi = -Oi, which is my second formula. As for algebra, I've checked multiple times and it seems fine. I just need an extra pair of eyes to check over everything.

Comment: What do you mean that $O_i$ and $E_i$ are the same? Do you mean that $\sum_i O_i-E_i=0$?

Comment: Sorry for the bad wording. What I meant was $\sum_iO_i=\sum_iE_i$
So:  
$X^2=\sum_i\frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}\\
=\sum_i\frac{O_i^2-2O_iE_i+E_i^2}{E_i}\\
=\sum_i\frac{O_i^2}{E_i}-\sum_i\frac{2O_iE_i}{E_i}+\sum_i\frac{E_i^2}{E_i}\\
=\sum_i\frac{O_i^2}{E_i}-\sum_i2O_i+\sum_iE_i\\
=\sum_i\frac{O_i^2}{E_i}-\sum_i2O_i+\sum_iO_i\\
=\sum_i\frac{O_i^2}{E_i}-\sum_iO_i$

Answer (score 1):

Your algebra is fine. The problem is that your values for $E_i$ are incorrect!

If you check, you will find that $\Sigma O_i=200$ and $\Sigma E_i=199.92$

You have a problem because in your case $\Sigma O_i \ne \Sigma E_i$

I think an error has ben made in the "$\ge 2$" column. I guess  the value for $E_i$ should read $25.04$ instead of $24.96$